# How to allow QWebView to display desktop Notifications?

Tags: python-3.x, webkit, pyqt4, qtwebkit, qwebview

Using Python 3 and PyQT, I've built a simple program to run a specific web chat.

This site uses desktop Notifications, and when running inside a external browser, it automatically asks the user for Notification grants.

Inside QWebView, the browser grant confirm dialog is never displayed, even when I click in a button that explicitly request permission.

**Additional Info**: I can see in the console, while enabling `QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled`, there is a `Notification` object with `default` permission (which doesn't allow Notifications to be displayed).

Is there a way to enable Notifications on QWebView? Or at least make it display the grant confirm dialog?

Comment: One possible workaround I thought: use qtwebkit-bridge and build a native Notification object. But I don't know if I can override webkit Notification.

Answer (score 3):

## Enabling HTML5 Notifications

WebKit has a plugin system, a bit obscure, but QupZilla guys made a plugin to get the notifications working with QWebView.

There is the source code for them in the [QupZilla plugins project](https://github.com/QupZilla/qtwebkit-plugins). Just compile and install using the simple steps provide in the project and you're done: now your webkit will be able to show notifications.

**But your app will be not able to use them by default.**

Your app will be able to use then only if the web page request for notifications. Your app cannot force it.

A simple sample:

```
class Wrapper(QWebView):

    def __init__(self, window):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        # Other stuff here, like load URL, etc
        self.page().featurePermissionRequested.connect(self.permissionRequested)

    def permissionRequested(self, frame, feature):
        self.page().setFeaturePermission(frame, feature, QWebPage.PermissionGrantedByUser)
```

This will catch the JavaScript requesting permission to enable notifications.

## Alternative Solution

My first solution before find the QupZilla plugin was to use `qtwebkit-bridge`, so instead of use HTML5 notifications, I've injected JavaScript in the page to catch the calls for notifications, and then used native system notifications.

Comment: Additionally if you want a `.deb` package, I've built one for Ubuntu [here](https://launchpad.net/~rael-gc/+archive/ubuntu/scudcloud/+packages).